# Text label with several rows

Tags: html, css

2 things are bothering me atm...

First: 
I'm trying to create a contact section with few simple text input labels, one of which has several rows displayed. That would be the "message" ofc.
The problem is that i cant find where and how can i add those rows and limit how many cols can be typed in every row.

Second: 
How can i make them clickable/editable? When i add them to website they have placeholders but i cant click and enter text inside them (lets say to fill out a form)...


The code snippet is below, and THANK YOU for helping me to learn that stuff...

```css
.kontakt {
 display: block;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 border: 3px solid #20202f;
 border-radius: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
 font-size: 24px;
 background-color: rgba(51, 52, 89, 0.85);
}

#yourname {
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#mail {
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#message {
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.messagebutton {
 width: 75px;
 height: 35px;
 font-size: 15px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #bfbfff;
 color: black;
 margin-left: 172px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="kontakt">
   <div class="nametext">
    <label for="ime">your name</label> 
   </div>
   <div class="namebox">
    <input type="text" id="yourname" placeholder="your name">
   </div>
   <div class="mailtext">
    <label for="mail">e-mail</label>
   </div>
   <div class="mailbox">
    <input type="email" id="mail" placeholder="your email">
   </div>
   <div class="messagetext">
    <label for="Message">message</label>
   </div>
   <div class="messagebox">
    <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Your message goes here">
   </div>
    
   <button type="button" class="messagebutton">SEND</button>
   
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awesome stuff!

To get a multi-line message, use the textarea tag, rather than the input. So,

```
    <div class="messagebox">
        <textarea id="message" rows="3" placeholder="Your message goes here"></textarea>
    </div>
```

The ROWS attribute will get your number of lines, or you can use the browser default.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

As for being editable, they are by default - and your example seems to be working correctly.

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for, thank you very much!